# I am not able to create a proxy while using Github for push cmd

Tags: css, html, github

1. I am not using any Login username and password
2. I don't have any server name in my LAN settings

Then how could I use the below mentioned command for creating proxy?

```
git config --global http.proxy http[s]://userName:password@proxyaddress:port
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be like this

```
git config --global http.proxy http[s]://address:port
```

These `address` and `port` represent the fields with the same names in LAN Settings in Internet Options.
The `[s]` means to put s after http if you want to use the proxy for secure addresses also